# Протопоп — с какой буквы писать?

Tags: орфография

С какой буквы пишется слово "протопоп": с большой или маленькой?
Например, "Житие Протопопа Аввакума" или "Житие протопопа Аввакума"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописные буквы употребляются в полных официальных наименованиях высших церковных должностных лиц, напр.: Патриарх Московский и всея Руси, Местоблюститель 
Патриаршего престола, Вселенский Константинопольский Патриарх, Верховный Патриарх-Католикос всех армян, Католикос-Патриарх всея Грузии, а также Папа Римский. Однако в 
неофициальных текстах наименования этих лиц (обычно неполные) пишутся со строчной буквы, напр.: благословение патриарха Алексия, приём у патриарха, резиденция папы (или римского 
папы). **Наименования других церковных званий и должностей также пишутся со строчной буквы**, напр.: митрополит Волоколамский и Юрьевский, архиепископ, кардинал, архимандрит, архиерей, епископ, игумен, дьякон, протодьякон. (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации под ред.Лопатина, 2007)
Протопоп — это старое, вышедшее из употребления ещё в начале XIX столетия, название протоиерея (старшего православного священника).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, тут нужно писать с маленькой буквы, посколько с большой пишутся только высшие духовные звания.

Comment: Я тоже так думал, пока не встретил в списке литературы к статье написание с большой буквы, может опечатка

Answer (score 0):

Нет причин для заглавной. Протопоп, кстати, всего лишь - протоиерей, "утнер-поп", так сказать. С чего бы ему писаться с прописной?